# Java Streams - Sort element in each List while using Collector groupingBy

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, collectors, groupingby

I have the following code, which makes use of the collector `groupingBy()`

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears", "toads", "tarantullas");

Map<Integer, ?> map7 = stream.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        String::length,
        Collectors.mapping(s -> s.charAt(0),
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    ));

System.out.println("map7: " + map7);
System.out.println("value type: " + map7.get(5).getClass());
```

*Output:*

```
map7: {5=[l, b, t], 6=[t], 11=[t]}
value type: java.util.ArrayList
```

How can I **sort** letters in each list, and what should be the appropriate type of map's value?

Answer (score 4):

The proper type of map according to the *downstream collector* of `groupingBy` should be `Map<Integer,List<Character>>`.

To sort each list of characters, you can make use of the *collector* [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)).

```java
Map<Integer, List<Character>> charactersByLength = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears", "toads", "tarantullas")
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        String::length,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(s -> s.charAt(0), Collectors.toList()),
            list -> { list.sort(null); return list; }
        )
    ));
```

***Sidenote:*** try to use more meaningful names than `map7`. When your code base is larger than a couple of tiny classes, it helps a lot in debugging and maintaining the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)` to get a sorted `Set` and accordingly you can replace `?` with `SortedSet<Character>`.

```
Map<Integer, SortedSet<Character>> map7 = ohMy.collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        String::length,
                        Collectors.mapping(s -> s.charAt(0),
                                Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))));
```

**Output**:

```
map7:{5=[b, l, t], 6=[t], 11=[t]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`sorted()`** method on `stream` and then collect it by using **`groupingBy`** feature.

1. **`filter(Objects::nonNull)` :** It will filter out the non-null values before performing the sorted operation. It will handle the `NullPointerException` as it will filter out the `null` records.
2. **`.sorted()`:** It will sort the stream before the grouping of the stream.

*The code as follows:*

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("lions", "tigers", "bears", "toads", "tarantullas");
        Map<Integer, List<Character>> sortedData =
                stream.filter(Objects::nonNull).sorted()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length,
                                Collectors.mapping(y -> y.charAt(0),Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(sortedData);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{5=[b, l, t], 6=[t], 11=[t]}
```